# Physical switch that can be toggled by Raspberry PI

Tags: gpio

I've a raspberryy pi setup which can control a light bulb using the GPIO pins and a SSR. The problem is that I'd also like to use the physical switch to control the light bulb (so people don't freak out when they can't turn the light on/off)

Is there a switch component whose physical state (on/off) can be controlled by raspberry pi so I can keep it in sync with the state of the bulb?

Comment: Do you want to connect the physical switch to the Pi? Or do you want the switch to remain attached to the high-power? What is the problem with having the switch in the wrong state? Multiway switching has this same problem. Only recently switch have been kind of standardized in that up is off, and down is on.

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular switch and the relay together, as shown in the diagram here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#Traveler_system